# Display date and time

Tags: swift

In my app I get the date and time like this:

```
let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
```

And display the date and time like so:

```
let dateAndTime = ("\(day)-\(month)-\(year) at: \(hour):\(minute):\(second)")
```

This works fine, but if the `minute` and `second` are `<10` I would like it to show a 0 in front of the minute and second like this:
`11-8-2019 at: 21:06:03`
How can I do this

Comment: Use a `DateFormatter`. Much better than getting components and building your own string from the pieces. And it will be formatted properly for the user's locale (use date and time style, not a hardcoded format if being shown to the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **`DateFormatter`** to get the required date format.

**1.** Using `dateFormat`, i.e.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm:ss a"
print(formatter.string(from: date)) //13-Aug-2019 11:15:47 AM
```

**2.** Using `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`, i.e.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
print(formatter.string(from: date)) //Aug 13, 2019 at 11:15:16 AM
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `hh` without `a`. Or use `HH`. 2. It's much better to use date and time style instead of a date format when showing the date to the user.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the suggestion. Updated that.